# Facebook login not working using Facebook C# SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-javascript-sdk

The facebook login using the Facebook C# SDK was working, but now is not! What happened?

I get the user to log in using the Javascript SDK. Then, when I get back to the page, I cannot find the session when I don't ask for the permissions:

```
(Using only the attribute)
[FacebookAuthorize(
        LoginUrl = "/Admin/Facebook/Login")]
```

When the attribute is as it should be, it simply doesn't enter the action method:

```
[FacebookAuthorize(
        LoginUrl = "/Admin/Facebook/Login",
        Perms = "publish_stream,create_event,email,offline_access,read_stream")]
```

Before I send the user to the action method, I verify using JavaScript that the user is actually logged in and it is always true:

```
if (response.session) {
        html = response.session.access_token;

        // Tests if necessary permissions are set.
        if (response.perms) {
            var perms = response.perms;

            if (perms.indexOf("publish_stream") != -1
                && perms.indexOf("email") != -1
                && perms.indexOf("create_event") != -1
                && perms.indexOf("offline_access") != -1
                && perms.indexOf("read_stream") != -1
```

What do you think the problem is?

Comment: Did you upgrade versions of the C# SDK? Does this happen in all browsers? What are you your migration settings for your Facebook Application?

Comment: Yes, this happens in all browsers. I will update you with the Facebook application settings in a few hours when I get home. Thank you.

Comment: FYI, all migrations should be enabled if you are using the most recent release (4.1.1).

Comment: My Internet connection is not working at home which is where I am working with the SDK. I'll get back to this question as soon as I can, do as you suggest and report the success.

Comment: @Nathan Totten, Finally! I have an Internet connection at home. I downloaded the most recent release and apparently the bug, whatever it was, is now corrected. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the latest version of the SDK?

Comment: read my last commented dated from 1 year ago. It worked. But thanks anyway!

Comment: Excellent.  Sorry I missed that.  Good to hear. Can you close this question so it doesn't appear on the open list?  Thanks  :)